# JavaCpp: How to Specify the Native Library?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, g++, shared-libraries, javacpp

Where does JavaCpp look for the native library `libmynativelib.so` when it creates the jni library, `/linux-x86_64/libjnimynativelib.so`?

JavaCpp is told about the C++ header and shared library using the `@Platform` annotation like this:

```
@Platform(include={"MyLibraryHeader.h"}, link = "mynativelib")
@Namespace("mynamespace")
public class MyLibrary {
  ...
}
```

The above Java class is then compiled and run through JavaCpp like this:

```
javac -cp javacpp.jar MyLibrary.java
java -jar javacpp.jar -cp ../..   # classpath is parent of com/mypackage dir
```

Then JavaCpp output:

```
Generating /<projpath>/jniMyLibrary.cpp
Compiling /<projpath>/linux-x86_64/libjniMyLibrary.so
g++ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux <path>/jniMyLibrary.cpp -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/ -march=x86-64 -m64 -Wall -O3 -fPIC -shared -s -o /<projpath>/linux-x86_64/libjnimynativelibrary.so -lmynativelib
```

Which gives this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmynativelib
```

g++ is not finding `libmynativelib.so` either in the current dir () or in the linux-x86_64 subdir.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<projdir>` doesn't help.

What is the recommended way to tell JavaCpp which native library to load?

Comment: What you're looking for is the `linkpath` value of the `@Platform` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Platform(link=)` annotation already specifies the native library for JavaCpp to link to:

```
@Platform(include="MyLibraryHeader.h", link="mynativelib")
```

So all that remains is to tell g++ where to find the library `libmynativelib.so`. This is done by sending the -L parameter to g++ through the JavaCpp `Xcompiler` directive:

```
java -jar javacpp.jar -cp ... Xcompiler -L<libdir>
```